# How to call a webservice including parameters list type in Smartface

Tags: web-services, smartface.io

I am trying to call a webservice in smartface by using Data Source Wizard. Webservice has input parameters whose types are list of int and some other basic types (int, string etc). Data Source Wizard sees these parameters (lists) as string not as list of int. When i try to call webservice (i  leave lists/strings empty) i am getting the following error.

"There has been a netwok error, please try again later"

Is there anyone who knows how to call such webservice in Smartface ?

Answer (score 0):

WebServices uses xml structure because of that reason all the inputs and outputs are should be string. It is hard to say the reason of that error.

I can suggest you to read the documents at the link ( Data & Network Section )

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/

Comment: do you think that i asked this question before reading related documents ? your answer is not helping me at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used this call 
SMF.storeVariable("EmailID","Pages.Page1.EditBox1.Text", false, false);
SMF.Net.EmailInsert.run();
but still my data is not going from my editbox to the webservice.